# Accessing a remote database using odbc

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, odbc

I am developing a new tool for my project using mfc to access a rempte database, read the contents and to display in a required format. I am new to programming using mfc. For this, I tried to access a remote database using odbc. For accessing the database I registered the data source in control panel. When I run this application in my system it works fine and I get the result in required format.

Now when I try to open this application from another system I'm getting an error. The application crashes.

Is it possible to make a generic application using odbc api so that the database can be accessed from anywhere without registering it? Or should I use only ole dB for this application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be great if you could tell us what you ended up doing...Thx.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to use ODBC to access a remote data source, many ODBC drivers use a wire protocol to talk to a database on another machine. The ODBC API is intended to be generic and abstract your application from the driver, so it is also possible to write a generic ODBC application that can use any ODBC driver. The architecture of ODBC uses a driver manager between the application and the actual ODBC driver to further the abstraction and isolate applications from some specific differences in drivers.

Now, that being said, to connect to a remote data source using ODBC, your ODBC driver must be capable of talking to a remote data source. This will differ based on the ODBC driver, some will be capable and some will only be intended for use with a local source, such as drivers for local files.

With respect to your actual problem, if you could provide details on what driver you're using, how you're making the connection, what the error is, and any other relevant details we may be able to help resolve your issue.

Comment: I went to Control Panel->Data Sources and added an User DSN. Since the database is in a SQL Server, I selected the SQL Server driver from the list. I used this DSN in my application. I know this is local to my machine only. How do I change the connect string and the DSN so that I can access from any machine?

Comment: my connect string is `connectString = _T("DSN=SqlServerTest;UID=<UserName>;PWD=<Password>;APP=Microsoft\x00ae Visual Studio .NET;WSID=<WorkStationID>;DATABASE=<DB Name>");`

Comment: As I said, it works fine in my machine. When I run this in another system, I get the error "Data Source name not found and no default driver specified"

Comment: DSNs are local to systems, to use the same connection string on another machine you must set up an identical DSN on that machine as well.